# How to add contact seller button in product page? (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

can someone help me with this issue in wordpress (woocommerce product page)? I want to add a button in my product page and name it (contact seller) and I want to link this button to the seller page. how can I do it ?

here is what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

I tried to google the issue and I couldn't find any answer, I don't know if I have to write a code or if I have to install some plugin. that's why I came here asking for help.

anyway thanks for your time and sorry if I didn't show what I've tried so far. because I'm using a template and I'm new to wordpress. so i'm just sharing my issue and hope someone would be able to help

Comment: Please include in your post what you tried so far; it's not a "write code for me" site.

Comment: I'm using a template on wordpress, what I tried was disabling the (Add to Cart) button by not adding any price. and I don't know how to add a button in the product page that's why i'm asking, I don't know if I need to write a code or I have to install some plugin because I'm new to wordpress.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for __all__ products or just some?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be to remove the default Woocommerce "add to cart" action hook and replace it with your own, something like this:

```
//
// Remove default Woocommerce "add to cart" button.
//
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);

//
// Add custom Woocommerce "contact seller" button.
//
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'lutrov_single_product_replacement_button_action', 30, 0);
function lutrov_single_product_replacement_button_action() {
    echo sprintf('<p><a class="button" href="%s">%s</a></p>', 'https://seller.com/', __('Contact seller'));
}
```

It would depend on your theme though. If you're using the [Generatepress](https://generatepress.com) theme framework, the above `woocommerce_single_product_summary` filter works. Check your theme's documentation, but the basic idea is the same.